# Alternate pronunciation for screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, music-notation

A visually impaired user of a musical ear-training website I created tells me her screen reader is not properly pronouncing key names. In a selector dropdown on the page I have the flatted key names spelled with the proper unicode runes for a musical accidentals, e.g D♭, E♭, etc.

The screen reader apparently has no pronunciation for this symbol. I could change labels to D-flat, E-flat, etc. She says these spellings are pronounced sensibly.

On the other hand, I'd like to retain proper musical spelling for unimpaired users.

Is there a construct in html or css that allows one to provide an alternate string that will be discovered and read by screen readers?

For reference, website is at https://etudes.ellisandgrant.com and the source code is at https://github.com/Michael-F-Ellis/infinite-etudes

Comment: are you looking for aria-label?

Comment: @karthick, not sure. I checked the definition on mozilla.org. It's not clear that it would work as a pronunciation alternative to the text within an option element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aria-label` is what you are looking for here. You should be able to put `aria-label="D flat"` and it will be read out correctly

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Might be a day or two before it can be tested with her screen reader.

Comment: `aria-label` works correctly.  My option tags are now of the form `<option value="gflat" aria-label="G-flat">G♭</option>`